# Hibernate: DB not reliably rolled back at end of UnitTests in spite of @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

We have a large application using Spring for application setup, initialisation and "wiring" and Hibernate as persistence framework. For that application we have a couple of unit tests which are causing us headaches because they again and again run "red" when executing them on our Jenkins build server.

These UnitTests execute and verify some rather complex and lengthy core-operations of our application and thus we considered it too complex and too much effort to mock the DB. Instead these UTs run against a real DB. Before the UTs are executed we create the objects required (the "pre-conditions"). Then we run a Test and then we verify the creation of certain objects, their status and values etc. All plain vanilla...

Since we run multiple tests in sequence which all need the same starting point these tests derive from a common parent class that has an `@Transactional` annotation. The purpose of that is that the DB is always rolled back after each unit-test so that the subsequent test can start from the same baseline.

That approach is working perfectly and reliably when executing the unit-tests "locally" (i.e. running a "mvn verify" on a developer's workstation). However, when we execute the very same tests on our Jenkins, then - not always but very often - these tests fail because there are too many objects being found after a test or due to constraint violations because certain objects already exist that shouldn't yet be there.
As we found out by adding **lots** of log-statements (because it's otherwise impossible to observe code running on Jenkins) the reason for these failures is, that the DB is occasionally not properly rolled back after a prior test. Thus there are left-overs from the previous test(s) in the DB and these then cause issue during subsequent tests.

What's puzzling us most is:
why are these tests failing ONLY when we execute them on Jenkins, but never when we run the very same tests locally? We are using absolute identical maven command line and code here, also same Java version, Maven version, etc.

We are by now sure that this has nothing to do with UTs being executed in parallel as we initially suspected. We disabled all options to run UTs in parallel, that the Maven Surefire plugin offers. Our log-statements also clearly show that the tests are perfectly serialized but again and again objects "pile up", i.e. after each test-method, the number of these objects that were supposed to have been removed/rolled back at the end of the test, are still there and their number increases which each test.

We also observed a certain "randomness" with this effect. Often, the Jenkins builds run fine for several commits and then suddenly (even *without any code change*, just by retriggering a new build of the same branch) start to run red. The DB, however, is getting re-initialized before each build & test-run, so that can not be the source of this effect.

Any idea anyone what could cause this? Why do the DB rollbacks that are supposed to be triggered by the `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation work reliable on our laptops but not on our build server? Any similar experiences and findings on that anyone?

Comment: What database are you using? Rollback also depends on the table engine(InnoDB0)

Comment: Never had such issues. Which database are you using?

Comment: We are using an Oracle DB (Oracle XE (Express Edition) on the developer workstations, a full Oracle DB server (v19.0.0) for the Jenkins builds)